# How to set AWS credentials as Environmental variable in Jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have added my `AWS Access Key` and `AWS Secret Key` in Jenkins using the AWS Credentials plugin.

[image: AWS credentials plug-in 1]

After that I added a new `AWS Credentials` param called `AWSCRED` in my project. Now I want to use the `AWS Access Key` and `AWS Secret Key` in the bash script I am running for my deployment. But it seems the `$AWSCRED` variable contains only the ID of the (I tried `echo $AWSCRED` in my bash) credential. How can I get access to or use the `Access Key ID` and `Secret Access Key`

[image: AWS credentials param]

Answer (score 1):

suppose you can try
$AWSCRED_USR
$AWSCRED_PSW
If this doesn't work then you can use "secret text" for aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key credentials and use it in pipeline

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        // Define agent details here
    }
    environment {
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID     = credentials('aws_access_key_id')
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = credentials('aws_secret_access_key')
    }
```

Comment: this doesnt seem to work if you later do say 'aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1 --no-include-email'